# Outbound SFTP forward proxy

Tags: networking, sftp

I have two web servers each with a public IP that make outbound SFTP connections to various SFTP servers to update content. I would like to setup a Forward proxy for SFTP outbound connections. Does such a proxy exist?

Comment: But... *why*???

Answer (score 1):

You can proxy SSH connections (and thus also SFTP which is encapsulated within a SSH connection) by using a generic SOCKS proxy. I am not aware of any protocol-specific proxies for SSH/SFTP.

(It would be easier to answer if you gave a hint about your ultimate objective. What is the purpose of wanting to have the proxy?)

**UPDATE**

### Using SSH to tunnel SSH through a proxy:

1. Install *tsocks* on the clients which are initiating the SFTP connections.
2. In your */etc/tsocks.conf* set the following:

   ```
   server = 127.0.0.1
   server_type = 5
   server_port = 1080
   ```
3. Open a background SSH connection to your SFTP proxy machine as follows:

   ```
   ssh -D 1080 -f -n -N ssh-proxy.example.com
   ```

   ...or if you want it to close automatically after 5 minutes:

   ```
   ssh -D 1080 -f -n ssh-proxy.example.com 'sleep 300'
   ```

   (If you do this from a script, you probably need to add `-i keyfile` in the client and a put a corresponding entry in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in the SFTP proxy server if you want to open the connection from a script without user attention.)
4. Run the SFTP operations through the proxy by using the *tsocks* wrapper:

   ```
   tsocks sftp destination-host.example.com
   ```

   (This SFTP connection will look in destination-host.example.com as if it was initiated from ssh-proxy.example.com.)

### Alternative method with [Dante](http://www.inet.no/dante/):

Alternatively you could install *dante-server* (a SOCKS proxy server software) on the proxy machine and configure your */etc/tsocks.conf* to connect there instead of 127.0.0.1. Then just run your SFTP operations with the *tsocks* wrapper as in the step 4 above. If you do this, you need to make sure that the *dante* server is configured so that it does not allow connections from unauthorized users.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My goal is to have all outbound SFTP connections look like they came from the same public IP, instead from the Public IP of the Web server that served the outbound SFTP connection.